# AddSelect using subqueries with multiple child element in Laravel App

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to execute the below query:

```
$s = Year::whereBetween('year', [Carbon::now()->subYears(1), Carbon::now()->addYears(2)])
    ->addSelect(['test_column' => State::withCount(['projects' => function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('technicalDescription', function ($q) {
            $q->where('start_year_id', '=', 'years.id');
        });
    }])->first()
])->get();
```

But I'm getting following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: select `{"id":1,"name":"Andaman & Nicobar Islands","country_id":null,"projects_count":0}` from `years` where `year` between 2019-06-27 12:22:12 and 2022-06-27 12:22:12 and `years`.`deleted_at` is null)

As per above query I've `Year` model:

```
class Year extends AbstractModel {

    public function startedProjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_technical_detail', 'start_year_id', 'project_id');
    }

    public function finishedProjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_technical_detail', 'end_year_id', 'project_id');
    }

}
```

My `State` Model has:

```
class State extends AbstractModel {

    public function projects()
    {
        return  $this->hasMany(Project::class,'state','id');
    }

}
```

My `Project` Model has:

```
class Project extends AbstractModel {

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class,'state','id');
    }

}
```

I want to have know the `projects` count which started in `year` in individual `state` Something like this:

```
data: [ 
    {
        "year": "2003",
        "Andaman": 0,
        "Maharastra": 10,
        "Gujrat": 233,
        ...
        ...
    }, 
    {
        "year": "2004",
        "Andaman": 10,
        "Maharastra": 80,
        "Gujrat": 123,
        ...
        ...
    }, 
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "Andaman": 20,
        "Maharastra": 40,
        "Gujrat": 103,
        ...
        ...
    }
]
```

I can do mapping of data to achieve the above output, but at-least my `addSelect` should work. Any better ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Remove `->first()` from your query